# Git rebase original project

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have forked a project. I am the sole maintainer. Now the original project has changed its master branch. Can I merge those changes in my development branch or in both my master and development branch?

I read about rebase but I'm not sure that's how it should be done in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to sync your fork, the instructions are explained [here](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/).

After following all those steps you would end up with your Master branch sync'ed with your upstream (the original project you forked from).

Now, if your development branch is based on master (I suppose so) then you would simply merge master into development

```
$git checkout development
$git merge --no-ff master development
```

Of course, you can also rebase, that's up to you. In that case you don't do the "git merge" part but:

```
$git rebase master
```